# Shopify Rest API: Fetch only orders with (or without) specific tag?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Using the Admin REST API, the docs say I can put tags on orders.  I dont see how to query a list of orders that do or more importantly do NOT contain a certain tag.

If I pull orders, I want to put a tag [pulled] on that order.  Then, next time I pull orders, I dont want to have to get all orders and loop thru them, looking for orders I dont already have.  So can I pull "orders not containing tag: Pulled"?

Comment: May not help you, but if you just switch to GraphQL, easy peasy, it is simple to query for orders with or without a tag. You cannot do it with RestAPI, so, bite the bullet, and spend the few minutes organized your call with GQL to get the work done.